# Finding time elapsed from two times in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Essentially I have two timestamps as `YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm` and I want to find the time elapsed in days.

Excel can do this either with just time or just the date but not when the two are combined. I realize that this is not an uncommon timestamp format, and there is probably some way to calculate this simply with Excel functionality.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of several questions in the past - so if someone wants to look for one of those and flag this question as a duplicate - that would probably be appropriate - but in the meantime:

[image: TimeQuestion1]
[image: TimeQuestion2]

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the timestamp to date only with INT(), giving you the following formula:

=INT(A1)-INT(B1)